# Condition for loops in java

Tags: java

I have 2 loops.

The first:

```
while(part[i].compareToIgnoreCase(part[i-1])<0) {
    smaller = myarr[i];
    myarr[i] = myarr[i-1];
    myarr[i-1] = smaller;
    i--;
    if(i<=0) {
    break;
}
```

The second:

```
while(Integer.parseInt(part[i]) < Integer.parseInt(part[i-1])) {
    smaller = myarr[i];
    myarr[i] = myarr[i-1];
    myarr[i-1] = smaller;
    i--;
    if(i<=0) {
    break;
}
```

If you notice, both the loops perform the same task. Just the conditions are different. The conditions can not be passed in together i.e.only one can be used at a time.(Because these loops are a part of a method and 2 String arrays with different content are passed in.)

Can I somehow merge both of these together and do something so that only one condition is picked up at a time?

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example (e.g. code, data, errors) as text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Why do you spam language tags? You specifically mention java. And please edit your question, it is very broad. Post the code.

Comment: You could pass a predicate to the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking how to take a `Predicate` (`BiPredicate<String, String>` to be precise) as a parameter.

```java
  public void bubbleSort(String[] part, BiPredicate<String, String> predicate) {
    while(predicate.test(part[i], part[i-1])) {
      // Do bubblesort stuff
    }
  }

  public void bubbleSort(String[] part) {
    if (isText) {
      bubbleSort(part, (l, r) -> l.compareToIgnoreCase(r) < 0);
    } else {
      bubbleSort(part, (l, r) -> Integer.parseInt(l) < Integer.parseInt(r));
    }
  }
```

That said there are better ways to sort arrays!  :)

```java
Arrays.sort(part, String::compareToIgnoreCase); // Sort by text
Arrays.sort(part, Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt)); // Sort by number
```